# Build my Own IP SAN with 2 server

Tags: raid, storage-area-network, software-raid

I want to take 2 machine, put five disk on each, 10 disk total on 2 servers. I want to build a raid with 10 disk but between 2 server.

Is it possible and wath software i need ?

http://pcquest.ciol.com/content/search/showarticle.asp?artid=95202

I know this technique, but i need to know if there a new way to do it, and if possible with windows product.

Comment: Windows or Linux ?

Comment: What do you mean by raid between two servers? Replication of the raids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [Openfiler](http://www.openfiler.com/) don't know any Windows solutions.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Sorry, if what you are asking is "can I make a RAID array that is physically on two different servers."  Your only option would be to make two different RAID arrays, one on each server, then find some way to make them appear as one for clients.  For Windows, you can look at using DFS (Distributed File System) for this.